# GAE: SimpleAuth not able set set_session() using FB ID in PROD

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, federated-identity

I am using SimpleAuth by Alex (https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth/) in my GAE application.

When I was using it in localhost, I am login successfully using fb and google id.

After I deployed to PROD, I can still login successfully for google ids but cant login using FB ID.

```
 def _on_signin(self, data, auth_info, provider):
"""Callback whenever a new or existing user is logging in.data is a user info dictionary.auth_info contains access token or oauth token and secret.
 """
auth_id = '%s:%s' % (provider, data['id'])
logging.info('Looking for a user with id %s', auth_id)
user = self.auth.store.user_model.get_by_auth_id(auth_id)
_attrs = self._to_user_model_attrs(data, self.USER_ATTRS[provider])
logging.error(_attrs)
logging.error(user)
if user:
    logging.info('Found existing user to log in')
    user.populate(**_attrs)
    user.put()
    logging.error(user.put())
    self.auth.set_session(self.auth.store.user_to_dict(user))
```

For FB login, I can get the values of the users and store it datastore. 
When I try to self.auth.set_session() which sets _auth cookie somehow for FB login it fails to create _auth cookie.

```
self.auth.set_session(self.auth.store.user_to_dict(user))
```

My authentication type is (Experimental)Federated Login.

I could not able to figure out why self.auth.set_session() doesn't able to create cookie for FB logins.

Comment: Federated Login probably has nothing to do with FB auth, if you're using their OAuth 2.0 (Graph) API. How do you know it isn't setting a cookie? Do you mean that self.auth.get_user_by_session() returns None after self.auth.set_session(...)? Also, could it be that you have some cached values in the browser? Try logging with Google and FB using Chrome Incognito and see if you get the same results.

Comment: Yes I used self.auth.get_user_by_session() to check. I used chrome incognito still the same results. For FB, set_session() actually sets the value during on_signin() func but when I redirect to '\profile, get_user_by_session() returns none for FB. One thing I observed is when execute the set_session it creates a cookie called _auth ( in localhost[fb,google] and in prod[google] case) but not for FB prod which I suspects causing to return none for get_user_by_session after redirect. Attached my log details for FB and google [http://i.imgur.com/FIbrQ.png]

Comment: Could it be something similar to this? https://groups.google.com/d/topic/gae-simpleauth/5nBLq9m0dy0/discussion It just looks like it...

Comment: I checked my code i couldn't find any other save_sessions(). To be sure i just copied your code and simulate the login.. Somehow i can not login in Fb in prod. my test app [testersrajini.appspot.com/ ] and code [github.com/rakeshviyak/example ]. I can login successfully for google and tweeter but not for fb. –

Comment: Could you try logging in with your FB account here? https://simpleauth.appspot.com

Comment: Yes I tried loging your app with my fb ID, cannot login. I found out actually other people can login into my app with their fb ID . Some issue with my fb ID. I should ask fb why ? Any idea why it happens.. Thanks a lot . At least now I can be sure it's the app problem.

Comment: Is it possible that you previously denied access to the app, the very first time you were trying to log in with that FB account? Try going to applications page on facebook and see if it isn't in some kind of "deny access" list.

Comment: Nope, all applications are given access. Also, I can access other applications like (some games,imdb,etc) using fb login. Even for simpleauth I can see fb details are stored in User db,tokens in usertoken db, just the session is getting reset when redirected to '/profile'! so I am confused whether it issue is particular to my id or with app.

Comment: I assume you've already tried creating a separated test facebook account, and using different browsers/computers/clearing browser cache?

Comment: Yeah, I tried using different accounts,lots of browsers(both mob,desktop), 3 computers and clearing cache. Only time it fails whenever i use my account. Also one occurrence , I received an error in android [chrome browser](http://imgur.com/GKyND).

Comment: Right. So, this seems to be really a problem with a single facebook account. Unfortunately, I have no idea what the problem could be. Maybe you could try contacting some dev relations team at facebook?

Comment: yeah sure, thanks for your help. I will keep u posted !